# Convert an equals operator to a Func<bool> for argument in an extension that iterates over IEnumerable

Tags: c#, list, foreach, extension-methods

I have an extension function:

```
public static IEnumerable<B> iterate<T, B>(this IEnumerable<T> source, 
Func<bool> condition, B TAddT, B TAddF)
    {
        foreach(T a in source)
        {
            if (condition()) yield return TAddT;
            else yield return TAddF;
        }
    }
```

and I have some code like this:

```
List<bool> bar = new List<bool>(); //Supposed to be binary digits
//add some stuff to bar
string a = new string (bar.iterate<bool, char>(a == true, '1', '0')); //Convert a true to a 1, and a false to a 0
```

How would I make this work? I don't have the slightest idea how to convert `a == true` to a `Func<bool>`

IE: if you have a `List<bool> bar` that contains: `{true, true, false, false}` and you were to run the iterate method and place the contents into a string, you would expect: `"1100"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it'd be pretty simple to do without writing an extension method. Just use select and the ternary operator.

```
var foo = bar.Select( a => a ? '1': '0');
```

If you insist on writing an extension method just for this, I guess it'd look like this:

```
static IEnumerable<char> Iterate(this IEnumerable<bool> source)
{
    return source.Select( a => a ? '1' : '0');
}
```

If you want to make it flexible with respect to type and value:

```
static IEnumerable<TOut> Iterate<TOut>(this IEnumerable<TIn> source, 
                                       Func<TIn, TOut> converter)
{
    return source.Select( a => converter(a));
}
```

and call it with

```
var foo = bar.Iterate(a => a ? '1' : '0');
```

And if I want to exactly implement your idea, it'd be:

```
static IEnumerable<TOut> Iterate<TOut>(this IEnumerable<TIn> source, 
                                       Func<TIn, bool> decider,
                                       TOut resultIfTrue,
                                       TOut resultIfFalse)
{
    return source.Select( a => decider(a) ? resultIfTrue : resultIfFalse);
}
```

and call it with

```
var foo = bar.Iterate<char>(a => a, '1', '0');
```

P.S. `Iterate` is an awful name for a LINQ extension method, seeing as all LINQ methods iterate in some fashion.

Comment: Alright, I will rename my method, and implement your version. I am not very familiar with LINQ. Do you perhaps know a good resource where I can learn about LINQ? Thanks too!

Comment: Yeah it was hard to learn at first. The key for me was understanding that the `=>` operator is just a shorthand for declaring a function, and understanding that the function is executed on each element. I don't know of one good resource to learn from, but keep at it!

Comment: Another question that doesn't deserve it's own thread, is there a LINQ function that does the same as this function? https://pastebin.com/r7sEsczd --Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While the function in itself is a little funky, you could make it work for any condition like so:

```
IEnumerable<TOut> SelectLeftRight<TSource, TOut>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
    Func<TSource, bool> selector, 
    TOut left, 
    TOut right) 
{
    return source.Select(input => selector(input) ? left : right);
}
```

Usage:

```
bool[] source =  { true, false };
var left = '1';
var right = '0';

var str = new string(source.SelectLeftRight(a => a, left, right));
```

Also possible with some other data types:

```
int[] source =  { 5, 3 };
var left = '1';
var right = '0';

var str = new string(source.SelectLeftRight(a => a > 4, left, right));
```

However, as you can see the implementation is less complex than the declaration, so it may not be worth having this method.